# Trouble when trying to access instances of webcomponents in the dom in Dart?

Tags: dom, dart, dart-webui

I have created a webcomponent called "color-item" and instantiated it throug adding its custom element tag in the html. I'we also given the elements id's like this:

```
<color-item id="colorItem1" color_text="LimeGreen" bg_color="LimeGreen" ></color-item>
<color-item id="colorItem2" color_text="green" bg_color="YellowGreen" ></color-item>
```

The compoenents show up just fine and behave as expected. However, when I try to access those elements (in the main loop) to do some fun things on them with Dart-code I just end up with errors. Here is how I have tried to access them:

```
    ColorItem color_Item1 = query("#colorItem1").xtag;
    ColorItem color_Item2 = query("#colorItem2").xtag;
```

That produces the following error:

```
    Breaking on exception: type 'DivElement' is not a subtype of type 'ColorItem' of 'color_Item1'.
```

I'we also tried casting like this:

```
    ColorItem color_Item1 = query("#colorItem1").xtag(ColorItem);
    ColorItem color_Item2 = query("#colorItem2").xtag(ColorItem);
```

That produces a similar error:

```
    Exception: type 'DivElement' is not a subtype of type 'ColorItem' of 'color_Item1'.
    Breaking on exception: Class 'DivElement' has no instance method 'call'.
```

The component itself is defined like this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>
   <element name="color-item" constructor="ColorItem" extends="div">
   <template>

   <style scoped>

      .color-box{
          cursor:pointer;
          padding:20px;            
          margin:10px;
          margin-left:0px;
          display:inline-block;

          width:auto;
          height:auto;
          position: relative;
          font-size: 24px;
          color:white;
          background-color:orange;
          border-radius:24px;
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          user-select: none;
         }

    </style>

    <div class="color-box" style="background-color:{{bg_color}}; color:{{text_color}}" on-click="swapColor()"> Color: <b>{{color_text}}</b> </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="ColorItem.dart"></script>
  </element>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and the script for the component looks like this:

```
    import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

    class ColorItem extends WebComponent {
      @observable
      String color_text ="orange";

      @observable
      String bg_color ="orange";

      @observable
      String text_color ="white";

      @observable
      ColorItem next_color_item =null;




      List<String> colors = new List<String>()
       ..add("LimeGreen")
       ..add("green")
       ..add("yellow")
       ..add("OrangeRed")
       ..add("red")
       ..add("purple")
       ..add("blue");


     int i = 0;


     String getNextColor(){
       i++;
       i%=colors.length;
       return colors[i];
     }

    void swapColor(){
      String oldColor = bg_color;
      String nextColor = getNextColor();
      bg_color = nextColor;
      color_text = nextColor;
      if(next_color_item!=null){
        next_color_item.bg_color = oldColor;
      next_color_item.color_text = oldColor;
    }

    }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the custom elements haven't been "ugraded" yet, so the `xtag` isn't set properly. The specific error you're seeing is odd though, because I would expect `xtag` to be null, not a `DivElement`.

Try this and see if it works:

```
Timer.run(() {
  ColorItem color_Item1 = query("#colorItem1").xtag;
  ColorItem color_Item2 = query("#colorItem2").xtag;
});
```

Comment: That worked Justin! :) But somehow it seems magical... I don't understand HOW the Timer is able to know when the callback code is runnable and then runs it. Does it just try over and over again? Or can it subscribe to a notification of when the elements have been "upgraded"? I'd love to understand the magic behind.

Comment: I also tried this in my code, and there is a difference in the object. It is a div without the Timer, but is a ColorItem with the Timer. @Justin, is this because the code gets placed in the async queue and gives the main process an opportunity to fully initialize?

Comment: @MrMambo007 Allan's theory is correct, there is no magic involved! Using Timer.run from within main() delays running the code (in the anonymous function) until after the main() loop has finished. At present web_ui isn't able to initialise the xtag of an element until after the main() loop has completed. I had a similar problem when trying to bind to custom event handlers on my web components. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362148/is-it-possible-to-declaratively-bind-a-customevent-handler-when-using-dart-web-u.

Comment: @ianmjones is correct. I consider this a pretty big usability issue with Web UI, and I hope we can fix it. It used to be the case that .xtag return null before the element was upgraded, which I think is slightly more obvious that something hasn't been initialized. Haveing .xtag change classes over time is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing;

```
<color-item id="colorItem1" color_text="LimeGreen" bg_color="LimeGreen" ></color-item>
<color-item id="colorItem2" color_text="green" bg_color="YellowGreen" ></color-item>
```

with

```
<div is="x-color-item" id="colorItem1" color_text="LimeGreen" bg_color="LimeGreen" ></div>
<div is"x-color-item" id="colorItem2" color_text="green" bg_color="YellowGreen" ></div>
```

and replace

```
<element name="color-item" constructor="ColorItem" extends="div">
```

with

```
<element name="x-color-item" constructor="ColorItem" extends="div">
```

and try to use code like the following in main;

```
var color_Item1 = query("#colorItem1").xtag;
  print(color_Item1.attributes);
  color_Item1.attributes.forEach((k,v){
    print('$k :: $v');
  });
var color_Item2 = query("#colorItem2").xtag;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Allan, but nothing changed. Same error message. The app crashes when it runs the "ColorItem color_Item1 = query("#colorItem1").xtag(ColorItem);" line

Comment: I have edited my post with an update. I think the variable is a DivElement, but var will make it work. Try the snippet I used in the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but could you try this?

```
<color-item 
  on-load='onLoadHandler($event)'
/>
```

Then in the main, foresee the handler :

```
void onLoadHandler(Event event) {
    DivElement theDiv = event.currentTarget as DivElement;
    // then the xtag
    theDiv.xtag.doSomethingVeryFunky();
}
```